# How to enable authorisation in Adyen Payment-Gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, adyen

I am getting below error while integrating Adyen Payment-Gateway in iOS

The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it in Adyen payment-gateway

Comment: hi can you guide me a little about adyen integration in iOS. I have made a test account and trying to hit adyen test payment api (https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v49/payments) but getting this response
{
"status": 403,
"errorCode": "010",
"message": "Not allowed",
"errorType": "security"
}

Comment: I am using my test account API KEY for authorisation

Comment: @User did you go through the documents... they have clear mention every steps

Comment: I read that one . I am getting stuck in one thing . I am using ThreeDS2Component for fingerprint authentication . but when I initialze. this component it is not presenting the fingerprint screen to user
let action = ThreeDS2FingerprintAction(token: token, paymentData: paymentdata)
                        let threeDS2Component = ThreeDS2Component()
                        threeDS2Component.delegate = self
           
                         
                        threeDS2Component.handle(action)

Comment: @User you should open an issue on there GitHub they are very quick they respond quick....they will guide you. I did't implement fingerprint...